# float: left works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I have a picture and text, and I want to align both of them to center (both horizontally and vertically).

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #181A1B;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

#profile-picture {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: inherit;
}

#introduction-paragraph {
  float: inherit;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="introduction">
    <img id="profile-picture" src="https://icon-library.net/images/profile-png-icon/profile-png-icon-15.jpg" alt="profile picture">
    <p id="introduction-paragraph">Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Now if I look through the Inspector, I can see that in Firefox:

[image: firefox inspector]

The value of `float` attribute is set to `left`, as it should be, since it's inheriting from `.introductoin`. But in Chrome:

[image: chrome inspector]

The value of `float` attribute is set to `none`, even though it understands that it's being inherited. As the result the two elements of `.introductoin` are not aligned horizontally in Chrome, but they are in Firefox. How can I fix this?

Version of each browser: `firefox 69.0-1` & `google-chrome 77.0.3865.75-1`.

[image: versions]

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! it demonstrates the problem I have perfectly.

Comment: IMO Chrome is doing right here, because float on flex items has no effect

Comment: *The inherit CSS keyword causes the element for which it is specified to take the computed value of the property from its parent element.* --> the computed value of float for a flex item is none, you can check this in the dev tools

Comment: ^ this said, to fix the issue continue using flex like you did on the upper container. Don't mix float with flex

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for you comments, I think I understand. I did notice that `float: left` had no effect on `flex` in Chrome, as you said. How can I **align elements of a div horizontally, in `display: flex`?**

Comment: you already did it for the container, use the same inside it